# Upon pressing floating action button background activity also initiate

Tags: android, floating-action-button

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeView"
    android:background="@color/white"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/today_date"
        android:orientation="vertical" >    

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"

            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:id="@+id/ll1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                />   

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:id="@+id/ll2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                />    
         </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:id="@+id/ll3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
             />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:id="@+id/ll4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
             >    
        </LinearLayout>    
    </LinearLayout>    
</LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_add_reminders"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_plus"
        app:backgroundTint="#ffffff"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

So whenever I press fab the background linear layout's attach activity is also open. So can anyone tell me what is the problem with the code? I don't know why this problem occurred even when put the FAB button outside the linear layout.

Java Code:-

```
fab=(FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab_add_reminders);

        fab.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

                //Set reminder dialog box appear
                openDialogToAddReminder();
                return false;
            }
        });


nightLL.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Constants.SelectedBucket="Night";
                startActivity(new Intent(Reminders.this, ListReminders.class));
            }
        });
```

Comment: The question is a little unclear. What happens when you click on the FAB?

Comment: its activity is also open.  @MohanadMohie

Comment: I still do not understand. Isn't the activity already running? The FAB will only do the code in its onClick, so what about your java code? Maybe somehow you are re-launching the activity?

Comment: on pressing background linear layout a new activity is open. If FAB is pressed then a dialog box should is open. But now both the operation is happening a new activity and dialog box is open.

Comment: I tried your XML code with an empty activity, and put `LinearLayout ll4`'s onClick to open a new activity, and `fab_add_reminders`'s onClick to show a toast. It is working as expected. You might want to share the java code as well.

Comment: I also tried it with the parent `LinearLayout`, and the `CoordinatorLayout relativeView`. Still the same normal behavior.

Comment: MohanadMohie has kinda pointed out your problem. You need to set an `OnClickListener` on the `FloatingActionButton`, either in code or in the layout XML. Otherwise, the clicks will pass through to the `View`s below it.

Comment: I have added the java code,  inCase you want to check it out. @MohanadMohie

Comment: I added a separate answer, please check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an `OnTouchListener` on the `FloatingActionButton` instead of an `OnClickListener`, and you are also returning false inside the `OnTouchListener`, which means the `fab` doesn't consume the touch event and passes it to the next view below it (`nightLL`).

Change your code to this:

```
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openDialogToAddReminder();
        }
    });
```

Or, if you want to use an `OnTouchListener` for any other reason, then use this code:

```
fab.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    Toast.makeText(FabClickActivity.this, "FAB Touch.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Glad to be of help.